# Where to download Scala RPM or DEB packages?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

One of the projects under the [official Scala git](https://github.com/scala) page is [scala-dist](https://github.com/scala/scala-dist), which contains code related to making native packages like msi, deb and rpm.

I'd love to get deb and rpm packages for Scala 2.10.2! Where can I download packages produced with scala-dist? If there's no place that I can download them from, is there a tutorial somewhere on how I can build these packages myself? Do the scripts in scala-dist still even work? Or are they abandon-ware?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point, it seems like they are not listed on the [Scala 2.10.2 download page](http://scala-lang.org/download/2.10.2.html).

But they are actually there, you can browse the [download directory](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/) directly to get them for any version that has them (2.9.2 and above).

For 2.10.2:

- [scala-2.10.2.deb](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.10.2.deb)
- [scala-2.10.2.rpm](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.10.2.rpm)

<strike>I [created an issue](https://github.com/scala/scala-lang/issues/113) to track this.</strike> **Edit**: this is now [fixed](http://scala-lang.org/download/2.10.2.html), the download pages have been updated.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is a pretty huge oversight given the number of "Getting Started With Scala" tutorials that involve manually making links and such.